# How do I get colors on a bokeh plot to line up with their correct values (log scale)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

My issue is similar to this discussion- https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5020

I am trying to theme points on a bokeh plot with a log scale coloring scheme, and have a colorbar that goes along with it. My "color values" (i.e. what I'm theming to range from around 1e-9 to 1e-3).

My issue right now is that I can get the colorbar to fit that defined color range appropriately using a LogColorMapper and LogTicker, but using the same LogColorMapper on the fill_color property on my points seems to be mapping incorrectly. See minimized example below:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LogTicker,Ticker,HoverTool
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.mappers import LinearColorMapper, LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6, Viridis3,Spectral11
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = np.linspace(0, 1000, num=1000)
y = [np.random.random()*1000 for x in range(0,1000)]
#generate a random lognormal list, median 1e-6 with standard deviation of 1 order of magnitude
z = 10**np.random.normal(-6, 1, size=1000)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y, z=z))

log_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=Viridis6, low=1e-9, high=1e-3)

custom_hover = HoverTool()
custom_hover.tooltips=[('Value','@z'),]

p = figure(x_axis_type='linear', toolbar_location='above',tools=[custom_hover])
opts = dict(x='x', line_color=None, source=source)
p.circle(y='y', fill_color={'field': 'z', 'transform': log_mapper}, legend="Log mapper", **opts)

colorbar = ColorBar(color_mapper=log_mapper,ticker=LogTicker(), location=(0,0), orientation='horizontal', padding=0)

p.add_layout(colorbar, 'below')

show(p)
```

When this plots up I get something like this
[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzRUL.jpg)

Using the hovertool to hover over points (sorry I don't know how to embed/link bokeh plots)... you'll see that the colors on the plot don't fit the point values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Alright, I figured this out with a workaround. It essentially has to do with the log transform between logcolorbar being different from the log transform for fill_color, and this causes problems for values between 0 and 1 (my domain). See my post here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8832

Answer (score 0):

user11705556 points out that this issue is solved by doing a
log transform between logcolorbar being different from the log transform for fill_color,
cf [the PR](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8832).

(I will delete this answer after user11705556 posts an answer to her own question.)

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in Bokeh 1.4 but is already resolved on master and will be in the upcoming 2.0 release. The original code functions as expected with 2.0 "dev" builds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer

I found the issue and managed a workaround. See this thread:

It essentially has to do with the log transform between logcolorbar being different from the log transform for fill_color, and this causes problems for values between 0 and 1 (my domain). See my post here: github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8832

Apparently this will be resolved in the next release, but in the meantime my workaround will do.